# Gravity Forms Required Fields

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, requiredfieldvalidator

I have created a new form in Gravity Forms but there does not seem to be anywhere I can specify 'Required fields" and have the form validate and fail if these fields are not filled in.

Does anyone know how to do this please?
Thanks

Comment: Made tags more specific.  Added some whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Expand each field to expose the settings tabs. The 'Required' checkbox is at the bottom of the General tab.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: Why? It is the answer. As an aside, I cannot comment, except apparently to my own answer...